# Model Output is MLMultiArray with 5 dimension like this Double 1 x 1 x 22 x 40 x 40

Tags: caffe, coreml

I have convert Caffe Model into CoreML model it takes an image as input and then predict output in the following format `Double 1 x 1 x 22 x 40 x 40` of type MLMultiArrray.

But now i want to reproduce an image from this Array. Can anybody help me ?

Comment: Create an image how? The 40x40 dimension could be used as the height and width, but an image either has 1, 3 or 4 color channels while you have 22 channels. How do you want to turn this into a color (or grayscale) image?

Comment: My CoreML Model is producing this output, Is there any issue with my .mlmodel ?
Actually i have converted a caffe model into .mlmodel using coremltools

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans Can you check this link

https://gist.github.com/otmb/7b2e1caf3330b97c82dc217af5844ad5

Comment: That's an OpenPose model. It does not produce images as output. Well, that's not entirely true: it creates 22 heatmaps, each of which you can treat as a separate grayscale image. Is that want you want to do, have 22 grayscale images?

Comment: I am working to detect human hand using this model, Now i have given image including human hand to model, and model is presenting output in this format.
Can you help me producing image showing some dots indicating hand through this MLMultiArray

Comment: I am working for last one month

Comment: You will have to figure out which of the 22 heatmaps corresponds to the hand, but then you can use one of the functions from CoreMLHelpers to turn this into a grayscale image. https://github.com/hollance/CoreMLHelpers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191558/discussion-between-akhzar-nazir-and-matthijs-hollemans).

Comment: What if i get value from mlmultiarray.image() like this , <UIImage > {1,1}
Is this 1,1 is correct image or there should be like this <UIImage > {40,40}
????